# Converting to Char/String from Ascii Int in Swift

Tags: string, swift, integer, ascii

I'm trying to convert the integer representation of an ascii character back into a string.

```
string += (char) int;
```

In other languages like Java (the example here) I can just cast the integer into a char. Swift obviously does not know these and I'm guessing using the all powerful NSString somehow will be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It may not be as clean as Java, but you can do it like this:

```
var string = ""
string.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(50)))
```

You can also modify the syntax to look more similar if you like:

```
//extend Character so it can created from an int literal
extension Character: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    public static func convertFromIntegerLiteral(value: IntegerLiteralType) -> Character {
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(value))
    }
}

//append a character to string with += operator
func += (inout left: String, right: Character) {
    left.append(right)
}

var string = ""
string += (50 as Character)
```

Or using dasblinkenlight's method:

```
func += (inout left: String, right: Int) {
    left += "\(UnicodeScalar(right))"
}
var string = ""
string += 50
```

Comment: That's a good point. And to clean it up, you could add the operator += `func += (inout left: String, right: Int) { left += "\(UnicodeScalar(right))"
}`

Comment: is there a way to get decimal value from character in swift

Comment: Looks like in Swift 5 it's renamed to `Character(Unicode.Scalar(50))` , tiny difference but thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a production-ready solution in **Swift 3**:

```swift
extension String {
    init(unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar) {
        self.init(Character(unicodeScalar))
    }


    init?(unicodeCodepoint: Int) {
        if let unicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(unicodeCodepoint) {
            self.init(unicodeScalar: unicodeScalar)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }


    static func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int) -> String {
        return lhs + String(unicodeCodepoint: rhs)!
    }


    static func +=(lhs: inout String, rhs: Int) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let a = String(unicodeCodepoint: 42) // "*"
var b = a + 126 // "*~"
b += 33 // "*~!"
```

Note that this works with all ASCII *and* Unicode codepoints, so you can do this:

```
var emoji = String(unicodeCodepoint: 0x1F469)! // ""
emoji += 0x200D // "‍"
emoji += 0x1F4BB // "‍"
```

---

As a personal note, I wouldn't use this in my code. I would have expected `":" + 40` to become `":40"`, not `":("`. If you prefer the second one where `40` becomes `"("`, then this should work well for you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want only String characters from A... you can use this func:

```
func characterFromInt(index : Int) -> String {
        let startingValue = Int(("A" as UnicodeScalar).value)
        var characterString = ""
        characterString.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(startingValue + index)))
        return characterString
    }
```