# Backspace (\b) Equivalent in swift language

Tags: ios, swift, character, special-characters

What is the `\b` equivalent in swift? I have to split a string which is received from server with `\b`?

Comment: if there's no metachar like `\b`, you can always use ascii 8, which is what `\b` maps to in C-style strings.

Comment: How can I use it in a string like: `THIS\bIS\bA\bTEST`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799413/converting-to-char-string-from-ascii-int-in-swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From ["Strings and Characters"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) in the Swift
Reference:

> Special Characters in String Literals
>
> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters `\0` (null character), `\\` (backslash), `\t`
>     (horizontal tab), `\n` (line feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double
>     quote) and `\'` (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as
>     `\u{n}`, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to
>     a valid Unicode code point

So Swift does not have a special character for the backspace
character, like `\b` in the C language. You can use the Unicode
special character `\u{n}`:

```
let string = "THIS\u{8}IS\u{8}A\u{8}TEST"
```

or create a string from the Unicode value:

```
let bs = String(UnicodeScalar(8))
let string = "THIS\(bs)IS\(bs)A\(bs)TEST"
```