# How can I print the bell character / ring the system bell in Swift?

Tags: swift, unix, ascii

The system bell character is a non displayable character which makes a sound when printed to the terminal. It can be useful if you want to be alerted when something happened in your program.

It has the ASCII code 0x07 or \a, how can I print this character in Swift language?

```
// prints "7"
print("\07")

// compiler error
print("\a")
```

Comment: Similar: [Backspace (\b) Equivalent in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042489/backspace-b-equivalent-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print a unicode character in swift with the following escape sequence:

```
print("\u{7}")
```

Comment: FYI - you don't need the `0`. And Swift only supports `\0`, `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\"`, `\'`, and the double backslash. (BTW - not my down vote).

Comment: some will say its a duplicate, but when the next person searches "Print bell character in swift" as I did, this will be the top result