# Errors when printing Unicode Grapheme Clusters by a for loop

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I would like to print out the grapheme clusters of which the code point from U+0021 to U+0100 in the Unicode table

```
for i in 21...100 {
    print("\u{i} ", terminator: "")
}
```

The compiler presented me the following error

[image]

**Question**: I guess I can't use the index from the for loop array as the Unicode Scalar indicator in the string interpretation. If so, what steps should I change to use the loop correctly

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know swift so this could be totally wrong but do you need to cast from int to char.

Comment: What output do you expect when `i in 21...21`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799413/converting-to-char-string-from-ascii-int-in-swift or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259425/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-character-in-swift

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\u{n}` special character works only with a *literal* hexadecimal number `n`.
But you can *create* a unicode scalar from its numerical value:

```
for i in 0x21...0x100 {
    print(UnicodeScalar(i), terminator: "")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin